# Phaser Sprite body returning undefined on input on

Tags: angular, typescript, phaser-framework

I am trying to flick whenever i click the mouse but the variable on `input.on` is returning undefined upon clicking the mouse down here is the snippet. Phaser is new to me

```
    w : number;
    h : number;
    velocity:number;
    sprite = null;
    totalDelta = null;

    constructor() {
        super({ key: 'Init' });
    }

    preload(){
      this.w = Number(this.game.config.width);
      this.h = Number(this.game.config.height);
      this.velocity = Number(this.game.config.physics.arcade.gravity.y);
      this.createBG();
    }


    createBG(){
      this.add.image(0,0,'background').setOrigin(0);
    }

    createSprite(){
      var x = this.w * 0.1; 
      this.sprite = this.physics.add.sprite(x ,this.h/2,'sprite').setOrigin(0);
    }

    create(){
      this.createSprite();
      this.input.on("pointerdown",this.flick);
    }

    flick(){
      this.sprite.body.velocity.y = -this.velocity;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that you have to pass the *correct* context, to the `on` eventlistener. Here a [link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Input.InputPlugin.html)

```
// pass the context, as third parameter
this.input.on("pointerdown", this.flick, this);
```

**P.s.:** or you can use a *arrow function*, if you don't want to pass the context. I don't recommend doing this, but just to show an alternative option, and many is good to know since many people use this way of coding.
Here a link to the [documentation for arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

With other words, this also works:

```
this.input.on("pointerdown", () => this.flick());
```

Comment: wow thank you so much it wasn't on the udemy tutorial that i enrolled myself .

Comment: @ralphy sure thing. btw.: if you use a arrow function you wont have to use the context.