# Phaser 3 can't get the start method to work right

Tags: menu, phaser-framework, scene

I'm trying to make a menu where the scene changes when the player clicks a button using the start method. At first, I had it all in the create function with this:

```
var levelOne = this.add.sprite(200, 400, 'LevelOne').setInteractive();

    levelOne.on('pointerdown', function (pointer) {

      this.scene.start('play');
      
  });
```

But this led to an error in which it said that this.scene.start isn't a function.

I looked at a previous example where the method worked, the big difference was that the method was in the update function, so I rewrote my code to have this in the create function:

```
this.choice = 0;

    var levelOne = this.add.sprite(200, 400, 'LevelOne').setInteractive();

    levelOne.on('pointerdown', function (pointer) {

      this.choice = 1;
      //game.settings = {
        //gameTimer: 60000    
      //}

  });
```

And this in the update function:

```
if (this.choice == 1){
    this.scene.start('play'); 
}
```

Sadly, this didn't work either and didn't even give an error message. I can't tell what went wrong. Please help.

Comment: This is the same question, just noticed it. [Phaser Sprite body returning undefined on input on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73839620/phaser-sprite-body-returning-undefined-on-input-on)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the `scene` as the context to the event function  `on(...)` ([link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Input.InputPlugin.html#on__anchor)), as the third parameter, so that you can access the `scene` properties and functions in the event callback.

```
levelOne.on('pointerdown', function (pointer) {
    this.scene.start('play');    
}, this); // <-- you have to add "this"
```